# PowerShell Windows Forms GUI, boxes flickering and changing position instead of being static (text has been outputed)

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-forms-designer

I have been trying to create a input text box in PowerShell using some .NET classes. As I am not so familiar to those classes I have been struggling a bit.
I am able to create all the boxes and fields, even capture the texts. The problem is that the boxes in the GUI change their positions vertically and horizontally (I discovered that when I was inputting some text and clicking in the button "add" to add more boxes to the windows form). I tried to modify it a lot of times but it still changes its position.
I the problem is in the function "Add-Row"

```
function form($title, $incidentnumber, $justification){
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
#######creating from######
$global:form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$global:form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(900, 600)
$global:form.SuspendLayout() #anchor for ensure that everything is loaded in the end
$global:form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" 
$global:form.Text=$title
#######labels#######
####Text Label 1
$textLabel1=New-Object "System.Windows.Forms.Label";
$textLabel1.Top=10
$textLabel1.Text=$incidentnumber
$textLabel1.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$textLabel1.Left=25-($incidentnumber.Length)/2
####Text Label 2
$textLabel2=New-Object "System.Windows.Forms.Label";
$textLabel2.Top=10
$textLabel2.Text=$justification
$textLabel2.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$textLabel2.Left=375-($justification.Length)/2
########new panel########
$dp = New-Object Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
########buttons#########
####Define OK button
$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Width = 100
$button.Text = “Ok”
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(775,525)
####Define cancel button
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Width = 100
$button1.Text = “Cancel”
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(665,525)
####Define add incident button
$button2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Text = "Add Incident"
$button2.Add_Click({Add-Row})
$button2.Width = 100
$button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(175,525)
####Define instructions button
$button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button3.Width = 100
$button3.Text = “Instructions”
$button3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,525)

$global:k = 0
$global:vetor = New-Object 'object[,]' 1,1 

Function Add-Row {
    $script:dp.GrowStyle
    $zeroBasedRow = $script:dp.RowCount
        $rowcount = $dp.GrowStyle
    for ($i=0; $i -lt 2; $i++) {
        $textbox=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $textbox.Width = 300
        $textbox.Margin = 25
        $defaultValue=""
        $textbox.Text=$defaultValue
        $textbox | Set-Variable -Name "textbox$global:k" -Value $textbox.Text -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $dp.Controls.Add($textbox,$i,$zeroBasedRow)
        }
   }



Function Create-Data-Panel ($width, $height) {

    $dataPanel = New-Object Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
    $dataPanel.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @($width,$height)
        $dataPanel.Top = 30
    $dataPanel.AutoScroll = $true
    $dataPanel.BackColor = "Transparent"
    $dataPanel.CellBorderStyle = "None"
    $dataPanel.RowCount = 0
    $dataPanel.ColumnCount = 2  


    $dataPanel
}

$hght = $form.size.height * 3/4
$dp = Create-Data-Panel 880 490

##################handlers and more clicks ########
$eventHandler = {
$form.Close() 
}
$button.Add_Click($eventHandler)

####event handler object for cancel button
$eventHandler1 = [System.EventHandler]{
$global:vetor = $null
$form.Close() 
}

$button1.Add_Click($eventHandler1)

$Button_Click = 
{

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Type: 1 = Accepted, 0 = Not Accepted", "Instructions")
}

$button3.Add_Click($Button_Click)


##########add controls##############
$form.Controls.Add($dp)
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel1)
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel2)
$form.Controls.Add($button)
$form.Controls.Add($button1)
$form.Controls.Add($button2)
$form.Controls.Add($button3)
$form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )    
$form.ResumeLayout()
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null


########return values in $return (texts)#######

$global:vetor
}
```

Any solutions to help me? Modifications???

Comment: `$dp.Controls.Add($textbox,$i,$zeroBasedRow)` --> `$dp.Controls.Add($textbox)`. If you want to store the column and row number with each box, use the `.Tag` property of the textbox. Perhaps like this: `$textbox.Tag = "$i,$zeroBasedRow"`

Comment: Nice, it worked! However there is an exception "The property 'Tag' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set." Perhaps, I should put some -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue.

Comment: Oh yes, a textbox really **does** have a `.Tag` property. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox)..